# Large container file overwritten by empty file (0 b) on external NTFS volume

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

In order to build a new container file on an external NTFS volume using the terminal command dd, I unintentionally overwrote the existing container (280G). Fortunately, I realized the mistake immediately, so that I could cancel the process before anything has been written on the disk.
However, the file was replaced by a 0 byte file of the same name, so testdisk could not locate it as a deleted, eventually recoverable file.
As a next step, I renamed the new 0 byte file hoping the old filename would appear again in the list of deleted files in testdisk. But this failed, too.
Now I have no idea how to recover the container, which certainly is still on the disk, because nothing has been written to it physically.
Anyone has an idea?
Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: turn off PC asap, boot from a live CD with recovery software. You might have a chance it hasn't been overwritten.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)